# DateTime object to worded date

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

How would I go about converting a datetime object (e.g. `DateTime(2000, 1, 30)`) to the worded date (January 30th, 2000)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html), you can see you have the following methods exposed:

- [Day property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/DateTime/day.html)
- [Month property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/DateTime/month.html)
- [Year property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/DateTime/year.html)

To convert the month number into the name, you could just hold a mapping of month number to month name.

To handle the ending of each day (st/nd/rd/th), you could also create a helper method.

Then you can use:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 30);
String month = convertMonthToWord(date.month);
String wordedDate = month + date.day.toString() + date.year.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few ways to achieve this, as @tomerpacific said. Here's one of them:

```
String formatDate(DateTime date) {
    List<String> months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ];

    final day = date.day;
    final month = months[date.month - 1];
    final year = date.year;
    String dayOrderThing = "th";
    if (day % 10 == 1 && day != 11) {
      dayOrderThing = "st";
    }
    if (day % 10 == 2 && day != 12) {
      dayOrderThing = "nd";
    }
    if (day % 10 == 3 && day != 13) {
      dayOrderThing = "rd";
    }
    return "$month $day$dayOrderThing, $year";
  }
```